# 2021 год в DatePicker

Tags: php, yii2

Установил на странице с помощью **yii2** поле, в которое вставляется дата (через **DatePicker**), но есть проблемы:
 1. Не форматируется дата
 2. Показывается год 2021

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'startDate')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),
    ['clientOptions' => 
    ['defaultDate' => '2016-04-01', 
     'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'lastDate')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),
    ['clientOptions' => 
    ['defaultDate' => '2016-05-01', 
     'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd']]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю почему, но когда в коде сделал правки, то ошибки решились.

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'startDate')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),
    [
        'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    ]
)
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'lastDate')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),
    [
        'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    ]
)
?>
```